# CakePHP - Paginate data after joining tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

I am having a problem about paginating the data from joining 2 tables. In my DB, I have 2 tables:

**Products:**

- product_id
- product_name

**Prices:**

- product_id
- product_price

The relationship between 2 tables is, a product can have many different prices (in many stores). I want to display a list of products and order them by the cheapest price. So, this is what I have done so far:

```
        $this->paginate = array(
            'joins' => array(
                    array(
                            'table' => 'price',
                            'alias' => 'Price',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                    'Product.product_id = Price.product_id'
                            )
                    )
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                    'Product.product_id',
                    'Product.product_name',
                    'MIN(Prices.product_price) AS min_price'
            ),
            'order' => array('min_price' => 'ASC'),
            'limit' => 10,
            'group' => 'Product.product_id'
        );
```

And here is the returned data after joining:

```
[Product] => Array
       (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_name] => iPhone 6 Plus 64GB
       )

[0] => Array
       (
            [min_price] => 20290000
       )
```

But the list can't be ordered by the new field 'min_price'. It is ordered by id. If I change the 'order' param to 'product_name', pagination works...

Comment: The name convention in CakePHp wants the ID of a table to be named "id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing the find, use a virtual field to define `min_price` as `MIN(Prices.product_price)` (as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries))

`$this->Product->virtualFields['min_price'] = 'MIN(Prices.product_price)';`

Then the find's field array is simplified to:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'price',
                        'alias' => 'Price',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'Product.product_id = Price.product_id'
                        )
                )
        ),
        'fields' => array(
                'Product.product_id',
                'Product.product_name',
                'min_price'
        ),
        'order' => array('min_price' => 'ASC'),
        'limit' => 10,
        'group' => 'Product.product_id'
    );
```